# How to upload a directory to the BG96 by using FILE AT commands?

Tags: at-command

I'm using the **AT+QFUPL="EUFS:/datatx/text.txt"** command for uploading a file to BG96 in EUFS under datatx folder. But how can I upload a directory to the EUFS storage?

Comment: What do you mean with "upload a directory"? Are you asking how to create a directory or how to upload all the files of a directory in a single step?

Comment: Furthermore: all the sources I found suggest DOS format for filename. Can you link a manual stating that a full path is permitted?

Comment: I meant how to create a directory in the file system of BG96 by using AT command

Comment: Find the link which I have referred, to upload files but I didn't found a command to create a directory. (http://183.82.99.162:8000/Quectel/NBIOT%20Module/BG96/01%20Software/Quectel_BG96_FILE_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.1.pdf)

Comment: Well, unfortunataly I'm afraid you can't, as such command doesn't exist. The document you linked, like the previous version I had, don't mention a command for creating a new directory. So, you'll have to operate within the directories pre-created by the vendor. I don't know if this is enough to write a full answer..

Comment: Yes exactly, I wanted to create a directory within the directories that are pre-created by the vendor.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not possible.